Unable to transfer ether from contract
I am learning Solidity and Blockchain and am following this tutorial I found for creating a Kickstarter campaign and allowing contributors to approve requests. These are my contracts:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.19;


contract CampaignHost {
    address public manager;

    mapping(address => Campaign) public campaigns;
    address[] public listOfCampaigns;

    constructor() {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function createCampaign(uint minContribution) public {
        Campaign newCampaign = new Campaign(minContribution, msg.sender);
        address campaignAddress = address(newCampaign);
        campaigns[campaignAddress] = newCampaign;
        listOfCampaigns.push(campaignAddress);
    }

    function getCampaigns() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return listOfCampaigns;
    }
}


contract Campaign {
    struct Request {
        string description;
        uint value;
        address payable recipient;
        mapping(address => bool) approvers;
        address[] listOfApprovers;
        uint approvalCount;
        bool complete;
    }
    address public manager;
    uint public minimumContribution;
    mapping(address => bool) public contributors;
    uint public contributorCount;
    Request[] public requests;

    modifier isManager() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    constructor(uint minContrib, address organizer) {
        minimumContribution = minContrib;
        manager = organizer;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);
        contributors[msg.sender] = true;
        contributorCount++;
    }

    function contribute() public payable {
        require(msg.value > minimumContribution);
        contributors[msg.sender] = true;
        contributorCount++;
    }

    function createRequest(
        string memory description,
        uint value,
        address recipient
    ) public isManager {
        Request storage newRequest = requests.push();
        newRequest.description = description;
        newRequest.value = value;
        newRequest.recipient = payable(recipient);
    }

    function approveRequest(uint requestIndex) public {
        require(contributors[msg.sender]);
        Request storage requestItem = requests[requestIndex];
        require(!requestItem.approvers[msg.sender]);
        requestItem.approvers[msg.sender] = true;
        requestItem.approvalCount++;
        requestItem.listOfApprovers.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function getApprovers(uint requestIndex) public view returns(address[] memory) {
        Request storage requestItem = requests[requestIndex];
        return requestItem.listOfApprovers;
    }

    function getRequestValue(uint requestIndex) public view returns(uint) {
        Request storage requestItem = requests[requestIndex];
        return requestItem.value;
    }

    function getRequestRecipient(uint requestIndex) public view returns(address) {
        Request storage requestItem = requests[requestIndex];
        return requestItem.recipient;
    }

    function finalizeRequest(uint requestIndex) public payable isManager {
        Request storage requestItem = requests[requestIndex];

        require(requestItem.approvalCount > contributorCount / 2);
        require(!requestItem.complete);

        requestItem.recipient.transfer(requestItem.value);
        requestItem.complete = true;
    }
}

I added a few addition getter methods on the Campaign contract to help with debugging. So far, I am using this only in test mode. This is the code I use to compile the contracts:
const solc = require('solc');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const sourcePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(sourcePath, 'utf8');

const contractConfig = {
language: 'Solidity',
sources: {
    'Campaign.sol': {
    content: source,
    },
},
settings: {
    outputSelection: {
    '*': {
        '*': ['*'],
    },
    },
},
};

const compiledContracts = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(contractConfig)));

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in compiledContracts.contracts['Campaign.sol']) {
    fs.outputJsonSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath, `${contract}.json`),
        compiledContracts.contracts['Campaign.sol'][contract]
    );
}

This is one test which is not working but is not failing. This is when the manager of a campaign wants to finalize a request when a majority of the contributors have approved the request. The balance of the contract increases with every contributor. However, the requested amount does not get transferred to the recipient which is a test account. I made a test where I transferred some ether from one test account to the intended recipient and that was done and the new balance is correctly updated. But the transfer from the contract to the test account does not work, but does not also fail. I tried console logging the error.
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache');
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const { abi: hostAbi, evm: hostEvm } = require('./../build/CampaignHost.json');
const {
  abi: campaignAbi,
  evm: campaignEvm,
} = require('./../build/Campaign.json');

let accounts, campaignHost, initialBalances, campaign;

const getAccountBalances = (accounts) => {
  const getBalances = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const accountBalances = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[i]);
        const balanceInEther = web3.utils.fromWei(balance, 'ether');
        accountBalances.push([balance, balanceInEther]);
      }
      resolve(accountBalances);
    } catch (_) {
      reject(null);
    }
  });

  return getBalances;
};

describe('Campaign', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    initialBalances = await getAccountBalances(accounts);

    campaignHost = await new web3.eth.Contract(hostAbi)
      .deploy({ data: hostEvm.bytecode.object })
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '10000000' });

    const minCampainContrib = web3.utils.toWei(1, 'ether');
    await campaignHost.methods
      .createCampaign(minCampainContrib)
      .send({ from: accounts[1], gas: '10000000' });

    const listOfCampaigns = await campaignHost.methods.getCampaigns().call();
    const newCampaignAddress = listOfCampaigns[listOfCampaigns.length - 1];
    campaign = await new web3.eth.Contract(campaignAbi, newCampaignAddress);
  });

  it('should allow manager to finalize request if approved by contributors', async () => {
    const campAddresses = await campaignHost.methods.getCampaigns().call();
    const campAddress = campAddresses[0];

    let contractBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(campAddress);

    console.log('INITIAL CONTRACT BALANCE');
    console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(contractBalance, 'ether'));

    try {
      await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[3],
        to: campAddress,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(1.5, 'ether'),
        gas: '10000000'
      });
      await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[4],
        to: campAddress,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(1.5, 'ether'),
        gas: '10000000'
      });
      await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[5],
        to: campAddress,
        value: web3.utils.toWei(1.5, 'ether'),
        gas: '10000000'
      });
    } catch (_) {
      console.log(_);
    }

    contractBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(campAddress);

    console.log('FINAL CONTRACT BALANCE');
    console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(contractBalance, 'ether'));

    try {
      await campaign.methods
        .createRequest('Some stuff', web3.utils.toWei(4, 'ether'), accounts[2])
        .send({ from: accounts[1], gas: '10000000' });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    try {
      await campaign.methods
        .approveRequest(0)
        .send({ from: accounts[3], gas: '10000000' });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    try {
      await campaign.methods
        .approveRequest(0)
        .send({ from: accounts[4], gas: '10000000' });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }

    let result = null;
    try {
      await campaign.methods.finalizeRequest(0).call({
        from: accounts[1],
        gas: '10000000',
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      result = e;
    }

    assert.equal(null, result);

    contractBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(campAddress);

    console.log('AFTER TRANSFER CONTRACT BALANCE');
    console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(contractBalance, 'ether'));

    const reqVal = await campaign.methods.getRequestValue(0).call();
    console.log('REQUEST VALUE');
    console.log(reqVal);

    let balances = await getAccountBalances(accounts);
    console.log(balances);

    const recep = await campaign.methods.getRequestRecipient(0).call();
    console.log(`RECIPIENT is ${recep}`);

    console.log(accounts);

    console.log('TEST TRANSFERING ETHER TO RECIPIENT')

    try {
      await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
        from: accounts[6],
        to: accounts[2],
        value: web3.utils.toWei(1, 'ether'),
        gas: '10000000'
      })
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }

    balances = await getAccountBalances(accounts);
    console.log(balances);
  });
});

This is the package.json file, in case you want to recreate the project:
{
  "name": "campaign",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
    "ganache": "^7.9.2",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.19",
    "web3": "^4.10.0"
  }
}


Can you also add the output of the console log statements in your question?

I think that campaign.methods.finalizeRequest(0).call( should be campaign.methods.finalizeRequest(0).send( instead. Basically at the end you're making a call instead of a transaction.

In the tutorial, the instructor creates the contribute function for accounts to send ether to the contract. In the Solidity documentation, I have read that a contract must have a receive() function or a fallback() function to be able to receive ether. Is that the case? I just checked, that the contribute function works just fine in test mode.

A contract can receive ether along any payable function. The receive function is a way to receive ether without passing any data, so the sender can treat the contract more like a normal wallet. In your case both are valid options.
